# What is difference between interquery parallelism and intraquery parallelism?

Tags: mysql

What is difference between interquery parallelism and intraquery parallelism ?

Comment: *interquery* means between different queries, *intraquery* means within the same query.

Comment: This sounds like a general question about databases, so maybe [cs.se] would be a better place to ask. But you should add more details to the question.